# Angular prevent setting model to undefined on invalid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

When validation fails on an input, the model is being set to `undefined`. Is there a way to prevent this. I'm on Angular version `1.4.8`.

E.g.

```
<input id="name" ng-model="inputname" minlength="4">
```

When I insert some value here and then reduce it to less than 4 characters the model `inputname` becomes `undefined`.

Comment: post you angular code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out, there is an option under [`ngModelOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) called `allowInvalid` which allows the `modelValue` to be updated with the `viewValue` even if it is invalid (instead of the default behaviour of setting it to `undefined`).

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions):

> `allowInvalid`: boolean value which indicates that the model can be set with values that did not validate correctly instead of the default behavior of setting the model to undefined.